# How to debug T-SQL code that is called from a C# unit test

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, t-sql

We are writing quite complicated T-SQL procedures and calling them from complex unit tests written in C#. We would desperately like to debug what is going on in the T-SQL that is being called from C#. Is this possible in Visual Studio 2010?

So far I haven't even got debug working in Visual Studio, but I'm happy to push on if it is available from C# code. My reading along the way leads me to believe it can only be done from database unit tests which is of little use to me.

Comment: Haven't tried it yet, but it would seem possible: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s0fk6z6e(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Thanks. This is where I started. It gave me my initial spark of hope and then led me down a (not so) merry path. There's lots about debugging T-SQL code from visual studio but doesn't seem to be any examples I can find where they start with c# code calling into sql server via LINQ and the like.

Comment: I have, occasionally, looked at the what's possible with T-SQL debugging, since probably about 2000. Whilst the promise is there, the execution has always disappointed, and I've inevitably ended up using old-skool "printf" debugging - liberally sprinkling `PRINT` or `RAISERROR` statements throughout the T-SQL code and inspecting such outputs. (Or including extra `SELECT`s if you need to inspect table contents)

Comment: Thanks Damien. My last 2 efforts have proven the same. Nice to know someone else experiences the same levels of frustration.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, *[Transact-SQL Debugging Limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/kkyhd4yb(v=vs.100))* seems to indicate that, yes, I can. I will push on and find out why that's not the case for me so far!